# Using neo4j fabric queries with java native driver

Tags: java, neo4j, driver

In my browser I can do this

```
:use fabric
use fabric.graph1 match(n) return n UNION use fabric.graph2 match (n) return n
```

This times out with:
*WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3*

But my actual question is how do I do the same thing using the Java driver
I can't do this

```
    session.run("USE fabric"); // Exception Query cannot conclude with USE GRAPH
```

or this

```
    session.run(":USE fabric"); // Syntax error
```

or this

```
session.run("use fabric.graph1 match(n) return n UNION use fabric.graph2 match (n) return n"); // Multiple graphs in the same query not allowed here. This feature is only available in a Fabric database.
```

or this

```
session.run("use fabric use fabric.graph1 match(n) return n UNION use fabric.graph2 match (n) return n"); // Exception USE can only appear at the beginning of a (sub-)query
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to connect using bolt to fix the first issue
2. you have to set the default database to fabric using an env var to fix the driver issues

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j Java driver connects to servers. Servers can have default databases per users.

`:use` as in the Neo4j Browser (or Cypher-Shell) is not a Cypher-Command. It's a browser respectively Cypher-Shell command, telling the corresponding tool to switch this session to another database on the server.

The pendant to this on the Java-Driver is the `SessionConfig` class and this builder method [`public static SessionConfig forDatabase(String database)`](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org.neo4j.driver/org/neo4j/driver/SessionConfig.html#forDatabase(java.lang.String)). In code:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.neo4j.driver.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.SessionConfig;

public class Thing {

    @Test
    void changeDatabaseShouldWork() {
        try (
            var driver = GraphDatabase.driver("neo4j://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "verysecret"));
            var session = driver.session(SessionConfig.forDatabase("fabric"))) { // <- Configure you session this way!
            session.run("use fabric.graph1 match(n) return n UNION use fabric.graph2 match (n) return n")
                .forEachRemaining(r -> {
                    System.out.println(r.get("n").asNode());
                });
        }
    }
}
```